# Set function Succ(Pascal)

Tags: function, pascal

How could I set in Pascal function Succ?
I mean when I put Succ in code it moves the ordinal number of character on next position. But only once. Is there way, that it could moves three times not just once?

I have found on the internet this code:

```
    function Succ (X: ordninal_type): ordninal_type;
    begin
      Ord (Succ (X)) = Ord (X) + 1;
    end;
```

My idea was to replace + 1 to + 3, but it puts me errors like:

> program.lpr(6,36) Error: Identifier not found "ordninal_type"
>   program.lpr(19,23) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Char",
>   expected "<erroneous type>"

So how should I set the function, so I would set it in code, like -> `CHARACTER:=Succ(CHARACTER);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Succ' returns the successor (next value) after the current one. It can't increment more than one, because there is only one "next value".

Use `Inc` instead:

```
Inc(YourVariable, 3);
```

Or you can directly increment in code:

```
YourVariable := YourVariable + 3;
```

If you're dealing with a character value (data type `Char`), you can use `Inc` as well:

```
Ch := 'A';
Inc(Ch, 3);  // Ch is now 'D'
```

Comment: Afaik INC is not Pascal but a TPism. But who uses std pascal nowadays ;_)

Comment: @Marco: I couldn't remember, which is why I gave both alternatives.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the other one too, I'm not even sure that (enum:=enum+5) is supported in TP. But I might be mistaken, in most of my old-skool times, Modula2 and ansi pascal were interweaved.

Comment: I didn't say anything about `enum` at all. I specifically used `YourVariable` to *not* specify a type.

Comment: succ works on all ordinals. My point with enum was that in e.g. TP, inc() afaik only works on integer types.

Comment: @Marco: Not true, at least according to XE5. 'type TMyEnum=(meOne, meTwo, meThree); var En: TMyEnum; En := meOne; Inc(En, 2);` compiles (and works) just fine.

Comment: @Marco: It works in D2007 as well, and the same code with a `  ShowMessage(GetEnumName( Typeinfo( TMyEnum ), Ord( En) ));` correctly shows `meThree`.

Comment: I said TP. This question has a Pascal tag, not a Delphi tag. I don't mind answering with Delphi since the two surviving Pascal's support it all just fine, but for correctness, humour me, and annotate any possible Delphi specific stuff with "this is Delphi, pre Delphi pascal's may react otherwise". I'll see if I can dig up TP, but that is not so easy anymore since I switched everything to 64-bit an year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Is that code exactly what you entered? If so, try "ordinal_type" instead of "ordninal_type"

I don't know if there are other problems here, but surely the type should be spelled correctly.

Comment: This is not an answer. It's a comment ("Is that? Try this.").

Comment: Since "ordninal" is spelled incorrectly on each of three mentions in the question, it seemed likely that the typo was made in the original code.

Comment: It doesn't make your coment an answer. :-) You're asking the poster to clarify whether they actually typed that, and suggesting they try changing it to something else. An answer is a statement that provides a definitive solution to the question asked. There's a reason they are separate things, after all. :-)

Comment: I suppose you must be right. I'll try to avoid making potentially useful suggestions in the future, for fear I might put them in the wrong place.

Comment: Jon, there's no reason to take things personally here. I was offering a constructive suggestion. If you have a suggestion, make it in a comment (that's one of the reasons they exist). Posting a suggestion as an answer can result in downvotes or deletions. I was trying to be polite and offer advice; as you can see, I didn't downvote your post. The [help] pages have information about the difference between comments and answers if you need more info.

Comment: Nothing personal. You just reminded me of what I most dislike about SO, and why I stopped bothering here a few months ago, and confirmed that that was probably the right decision.